# Migrated from Oracle XE to Oracle 11g (using Hiberate 3.6, Spring 3 and JPA 2)

Tags: web-services, oracle, hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0

I've an application built using Spring 3, Spring webservices 2.0 , JDK 1.6 and JPA 2 (with Hibernate 3.6 as the provider).

This application was working fine in Oracle XE. This application exposes few web-services, which I test using SoapUI. This web-service request contains date and time in the request. Application looks for the date and time equal to this request and returns the matching data.

All this was working very well in XE, but stopped in 11g. There are no errors or exceptions, I just don't get any data back in the response message?

Nothing else has been changed.

I've tried to use different Oracle dialect in persistence.xml but the problem remains.

Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: You need to isolate the problem. Can you determine what database call is failing? Can you simulate it in SQL*Plus?

Comment: When you don't accept answers, eventually you will stop getting answers.  Like now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. It was oracle installation issue. Reinstalled it and got it working.